# What is the meaning of "would" in this example?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, conditionals

> The label and concept **would be** focusing on experimental electronic oriented music. **I'll be bringing** out as always - unknown obscure tonal delights that goes hand in hand with coherent looking designed vinyl LP layouts which I print, craft, stamp and glue by myself.

1. Why "**would be**" and not "**will be**", as the label has just been created? Would is not used as a conditional here.
2. Why not **"I'll bring you"**? Does the continuous tense mean that this action of bring will last a long time without interruption?

Comment: You have forgotten to mention the **source** of the quote!

Comment: it was an email received one hour ago but the man who wrote it  is a native speaker

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about odd usage, since there are other issues. "Tonal delights" is plural, so it should be followed by "that *go*." The dash interrupts the sentence inappropriately. "Coherent looking designed vinyl LP layouts" is simply not coherent—the dash would be welcome in "coherent-looking," but what does it mean that they are simply "designed?" If some of the verb tense choices are unusual, I wouldn't try too hard to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, the *would* is used when talking about plans and intentions to make the declaration less committal and "softer", compared to a more definite and certain *will*. For example:

> The couch **will** go in the corner. *(I already know that, or have a strong resolve to make it happen; it's certain)*
>
> The couch **would** go in the corner. *(I'm thinking about it and maybe planning to do so, but I'm not as sure about it)*

As such, the sentence reads more as "that's the plan" than "that will definitely be the case" - which might be an odd choice for what seems to be a sales pitch, but it makes the pitch slightly more casual and less aggressive in its declarations, which might have been what the author was going for.

For the second question, the continuous aspect indicates that the author intends to keep bringing out the LPs over a longer period of time, rather than do so just once (as would be the case with *I'll bring*).